# Checking for same numbers of subdirectories in directories python

Tags: python

there I have some code with copy a files from `root-dirs-subdirs` and at beginning I would like to check, Did all dirs they've got same numbers of subdirs if not print a message something like `"nr subdirs not same`".I've got 5 dirs and each have to contain 12 subdirs(with different numbers of images).
Its exactly in

> for folder in src_folders:
>   src_sub_folders

I have no idea how to scan 5 dirs and get answer back, all what I can find is how to compare 2 dirs but how do it with 5 ??? Any help will be appreciated

```
from collections import defaultdict
import shutil
import os
import re
src_root = r'F:\img\img_test\2018-03-06'

dst_root = src_root + '-copie'

#os.makedirs(dst_root, exist_ok=True)

src_dirname, src_folders, _ = next(os.walk(src_root))
src_folders = sorted(src_folders)

src_folders = [os.path.join(src_root, folder) for folder in src_folders]
print(src_folders)
job = defaultdict(list)

print('mes {} dossier cam'.format(len(src_folders)))

for folder in src_folders:
    print()
    dirname, src_sub_folders, _ = next(os.walk(os.path.join(src_dirname, folder)))
    src_sub_folders = sorted(src_sub_folders, key=lambda x: [re.search(r'(\D+)', x).group(1)] + list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', x))))
    print("mes 5 CAM avec {} time laps '{}'".format(len(src_sub_folders), folder))

    for index, sub_folder in enumerate(src_sub_folders, start=1):
        job['Time Lapse-{}'.format(index)].append(os.path.join(dirname, sub_folder))



#print()

for dst_folder, src_folders in sorted(job.items()):
    for index, src_folder in enumerate(src_folders, start=1):
        dst_new_folder = os.path.join(dst_root, dst_folder, 'CAM-{}'.format(index))
        print('{} -> {}'.format(src_folder, dst_new_folder))
        shutil.copytree(src_folder, dst_new_folder)
#shutil.rmtree(src_root)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dst_root):
    for f in files:
        prefix = os.path.basename(root)
        prefix1 = os.path.basename(src_root)
        os.rename(os.path.join(root, f), os.path.join(root, "{}-{}-{}".format(prefix1, prefix, f)))
        print("images rennomer ")

print("fini")
print("dossier supprimé")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with a function to count the subdirectories of a given directory:

```
import os

def count_subdirectories(dir):
    return len([d for d in os.listdir(dir) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dir, d))])
```

Then a second function to call this for all the directories from your root:

```
def check_directories(root):
    for d in os.listdir(root):
        dir_to_check = os.path.join(root, d)
        if os.path.isdir(dir_to_check):
            print(count_subdirectories(dir_to_check))
```

This obviously only prints out the answers it finds, but that should be enough for you to go forward and compare these answers to either check they're all the same, or check they're all 12, or whatever you want.

## Comparing results

Edit: To compare the results, one way would be to use a `set`, like this:

```
def check_directories(root):
    subdirectory_counts = set()
    num_directories = 0
    for d in os.listdir(root):
        dir_to_check = os.path.join(root, d)
        if os.path.isdir(dir_to_check):
            num_subdirs = count_subdirectories(dir_to_check)
            num_directories += 1
            subdirectory_counts.add(num_subdirs)

    # Finished counting, now print the results
    if num_directories == 0:
        print("No directories found inside:", root)
    elif num_directories == 1:
        print("Only 1 directory found, with %d subdirectories" % num_subdirs)
    elif len(subdirectory_counts) == 1:
        print("%d directories found, all with %d subdirectories" % (num_directories, subdirectory_counts.pop()))
    else:
        print("nr subdirs not same:", sorted(subdirectory_counts))
```

If all the directories have the same number of subdirectories, then the length of the set `subdirectory_counts` will be `1` (because a `set` doesn't keep duplicates).

Comment: I don't know with path to use, you have 2 - dir and 2nd function root, but I have only one main src_root and inside I have 5 dirs(there will be all the time 5) , but subdirs inside can be more or less each time

Comment: Its ok I've got it

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your root is 'F:\img\img_test\2018-03-06' and your directories are all the directories under there.  Feel free to accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: Yes Constance it works , script showing all numbers of subdir from 5 dirs, but I cant figure out how to compare them, I have to split ? when Im using it have back AttributeError- os has no split, I tried filecmp and showing only objects ,

Comment: Couldn't find how to compare few dirs at same time and don't know how to rebuild it

Comment: Thanks a lot Constance :-)